# List class retaining old values for new list Python

Tags: python, list, class, object

I have created a list class with a few simple methods.

```
class ListQ(object):
    """List object creation"""
    def __init__(self, earlier_list=[]):
        self.list=earlier_list

    def isEmpty(self):
        """checks if list is empty"""
        if len(self.list)==0:
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)

    def put(self, new_item):
        """puts new_item last in list"""
        self.list.append(new_item)

    def get(self):
        """returns the next item in line"""
        self.first_item = self.list.pop(0)
        return self.first_item
```

I also have a function to help create these lists. (Helping to solve a magic card trick btw)

```
def create_card_list(card_list=None):
    """creates listQ of cards from user input"""
    if card_list!=None: #if user already has list of cards
        for item in card_list:
            item=replace_card_strings(item) #replaces any strings in list
            if item == False:
                print('One of your cards does not exist, list creation failed')
                return(False)
        cards=ListQ(card_list)
```

The replace_card_strings() function has been properly tested and I do not believe it's at fault but here it is anyway.

```
def replace_card_strings(word):
    """replaces strings of words with their numbers and returns edited list"""
    if type(word)!=int:
        if word.lower()=='one':
            word=1
        elif word.lower()=='two':
            word=2
        elif word.lower()=='three':
            word=3
        elif word.lower()=='four':
            word=4
        elif word.lower()=='five':
            word=5
        elif word.lower()=='six':
            word=6
        elif word.lower()=='seven':
            word=7
        elif word.lower()=='eight':
            word=8
        elif word.lower()=='nine':
            word=9
        elif word.lower()=='ten':
            word=10
        elif word.lower()=='jack':
            word=11
        elif word.lower()=='queen':
            word=12
        elif word.lower()=='king':
            word=13
        elif word.lower()=='ace':
            word=1
        else:
            word=False #if card doesnt exist
    return(word)
```

When I run the following test is when the problem start.

```
cards=create_card_list(['one', 2, 3])
one=cards.get()
two=cards.get()
three=cards.get()
print(one, two, three)
if one==1 and two==2 and three==3:
    print("create_card_list gives the correct answer")
else:
    print("create_card_list gives the wrong answer")
```

It prints that the function has given the wrong answer and
the `print(one, two, three)` prints `one 2 3` which is the original list.

Anybody have an idea where I've messed up?

Comment: You shouldn't have created the list class in the first place, since that is there already a list in Python.

Comment: Yes, I know but the assignment is to create this class so I do not have a choice.

Comment: Also, you *need* to copy the list in the ListQ constructor!

Comment: Please fix your indentation - paste all the code, select all, control-K to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not replacing items in the list, only in the loop's context:

Replace the entire loop:

```
    for item in card_list:
        item=replace_card_strings(item) #replaces any strings in list
        ....
```

Which does not do anything to the list (it does **not** "replace" the item).

With python's [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) which is used in order to apply a function to an iterable and create a list of results:

```
card_list = map(replace_card_strings, card_list)
```

If you don't want to use `map` you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
card_list = [replace_card_strings(card_str) for card_str in card_list]
```

Now you'll have:

```
def create_card_list(card_list=None):
    """creates listQ of cards from user input"""
    if card_list != None:
        card_list = map(replace_card_strings, card_list)
    cards=ListQ(card_list)
```

**Tip:**

You can replace the lengthy function `replace_card_strings`:

```
def replace_card_strings(word):
    """replaces strings of words with their numbers and returns edited list"""

    word = word.lower()

    string_to_int = {"one":1, "two":2 ...}

    return word in string_to_int and string_to_int[word]
```

This works since [`and`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) returns the last `Truth`-y result or the first `False`-y result.

You can also use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
# return word in string_to_int and string_to_int[word]
# try and read value from dict, return False otherwise
return string_to_int.get(word, False)
```

Which is cleaner (thanks @padraic).

**Tip 2:** You don't want two places referencing, and possibly mutating, the same list. It seems like you're keeping a reference to the same list that's used to construct a card list outside the generated object. This is prone to errors. What you should do is instead copy the list when it's passed:

```
def __init__(self, earlier_list=[]):
    self.list=earlier_list[:]
```

**Tip 3:** python has a [known "gotcha" with mutable default argument](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments), which is exactly what you use here (`earlier_list=[]`). This is prone to errors as well since python binds default arguments once. You should instead have:

```
def __init__(self, earlier_list=None):
    # copy passed list or create a new one if none passed.
    self.list=earlier_list[:] if earlier_list else []
```

Comment: Thank you for your help both with the problem and the extra tip!

Comment: I think `return string_to_int.get(word, False)` would be a bit nicer